# SQL stored function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am to write  a stored function to retrieve the number of items of a given product that have been delivered in the last year, and write a SQL Select statement that uses the function to display product no and name + no of items delivered in the last year for all products.

Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle?? Or both?? Also: please **show us** your table structure so we know what we're dealing with!

Comment: If possible oracle , Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Can you please let me knoe how can i add table structure here, sorry i am quite new here

Comment: Do you want a stored function AND a SQL Select to use the function of just a single SQL statement to retrieve the correct data?

Comment: Just make a screenshot in a visual designer or just give us the table name and the columns that make up that table (including their datatype) - something like the output from `DESC (tablename)` in Oracle

Comment: How do you want the data displayed?

Comment: marc-s , I have the screenshot of ERD design , where should i put it

Comment: Is this a class assignment?  Only it would in reality be much more efficient **not** to build and use a function to do this, but instead just to write the SQL query you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a delivery table and a product table.

```
create or replace function prod_delivered_cnt (p_prod_id in number) as
  v_res number;
begin
  select count(*) into v_res 
  from delivery_table d 
  where d.prod_id = p_prod_id 
  and d.date < to_date('2011', 'yyyy');
  return v_res;
end prod_delivered_cnt;

select p.prod_num, p.prod_name, prod_delivered_cnt(p.id) as cnt 
from product_table p;
```

Comment: Can you help me bit more please,create a function to retrieve the name of the manager for a employee table.  Write a SQL select statement that uses the function to produce a list of employee numbers and names together with the name of their manager

Comment: Sorry sir, that would be a new question, which I may also answer once this one is closed/accepted correctly. Also, please note all those comments suggesting to provide more details with such questions. I mean you should provide the table structure and the DB vendor if you want to get an answer that contains working code.

Comment: Thanks, I will put this question as new one. Also I am quite new here and don't have much idea how to put the ERD image over here, Can you please help me , It would be highly appriciated

Comment: Your WHERE clause will select all deliveries made except those executed this year.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably your question is prompted by a school or college assignment.  At least I hope it is, because using a function for this purpose is bad practice.  It performs badly, because of the constant switching between SQL and PL/SQL engines, and because it queries the deliveries on a row-by-row basis instead of using a set operation.

A simple pure SQL statement performs better.  I have chosen to use an outer join because you probably want to include products which haven't had any activity in the last year.

```
select p.product_id
       , p.product_name
       , count(d.delivery_id) as sales_this_year 
from products p
    left outer join deliveries d
         on (p.product_id = d.product_id)
where d.dispatch_date >= add_months(sysdate, -12)
group by p.product_id, p.product_name
/
```

I have interpreted "in the last year" to mean the last twelve months, hence the use of the ADD_MONTHS() function. A different interpretation would have a WHERE clause like this:

```
where d.dispatch_date between to_date('01-JAN-2010') and to_date('31-DEC-2010')
```

that is, last calendar year; or perhaps:

```
where d.dispatch_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
```

that is, this calendar year.